# Como envelopar o lote de envio da NFe no cabeçalho usando C#?

Tags: c#, xml

Olá, não tenho experiência com `WebServices`, mas estou tentando desenvolver um emissor de `NFCe` e já consegui autorizar algumas notas em ambiente de homologação. Gero o `XML` usando `C#`, então eu valido, assino e valido de novo comparando com o `xsd` da `sefaz`, porém quando enviei os arquivos tive que criar o cabeçalho no `notepad++` e depois carregar usando `XmlDocument` pra conseguir enviar, porque não consegui adicionar o Lote de envio no elemento `<nfeDadosMsg></nfeDadosMsg>`.

Resumindo preciso inserir um `xml` depois de um elemento de outro `xml`,
o código que uso é

```
public String CabecalhoEnvio(string cUF, int ambiente, String notaAssinada, String URlSoapAction)
{
    String retorno = String.Empty;
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(); // The writer closes this for us

    using (XmlTextWriter xml = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        xml.WriteStartDocument();
        xml.WriteStartElement("soap:Envelope");
        xml.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
        xml.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        xml.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        xml.WriteStartElement("soap:Header");
        xml.WriteStartElement("nfeCabecMsg");
        xml.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", URlSoapAction);
        xml.WriteElementString("cUF", cUF);
        xml.WriteElementString("versaoDados", "3.10");
        xml.WriteEndElement();
        xml.WriteEndElement();
        xml.WriteStartElement("soap:Body");
        xml.WriteStartElement("nfeDadosMsg", URlSoapAction);
        /*inserir o lote assinado aqui sem bugar o XML*/
        xml.WriteEndElement();
        xml.WriteEndElement();
        xml.WriteEndElement();
        xml.WriteEndDocument();
        xml.Flush();
        xml.Flush();

        StreamReader ler = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        retorno += ler.ReadToEnd();
    }
   return retorno;
}
```

esse código gera o seguinte xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeAutorizacao">
      <cUF>11</cUF>
      <versaoDados>3.10</versaoDados>
    </nfeCabecMsg>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeAutorizacao">
    adicionar o lote aqui;
    </nfeDadosMsg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Sempre insiro o `XmlDocument` no elemento `nfeDadosMsg` o arquivo fica cheio de caracteres estranhos tipo `?&??&&`. uso codificação `UTF-8` e o que preciso fazer é parecido com um *include* do `php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi tratando tudo como string e concatenando ao invés de inserir o lote como um novo nodo da mensagem Soap Ex: a mensagem Soap eu dividi em duas e concatenei com a string do lote.

```
String cabec1= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns...><nfeDadosMsg xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeAutorizacao\">";String cabec2 = "</nfeDadosMsg></soap:Body</soap:Envelope>";String loteSemDeclaracao = loteAssinado.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "");String retorno = cabec1+loteSemDeclaracao+cabec2;
```

a opção do CDATA não funcionou por que a tag do QRCode no lote xml já é um CDATA e é chato concatenar CDATAS como o J. Guilherme disse.
E de início o Replace não estava funcionando porque a formatação de código do Visual Studio adiciona espaços no "utf - 8" removi os espaços deixando "utf-8" e funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o CDATA:

```
<![CDATA[ *texto aqui* ]]>
```

Em um `XMLTextWrite` o método `writeCData(*xml aqui*)` deve ser o que você procura.

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isso, só que fiz o teste e me retornou uma Exception Não é possível haver ']]>' dentro de um bloco XML CDATA. Mas só tem as tags do xml mesmo

Comment: ao usar o método `WriteCData()`, o próprio método quem cuida dos sintaxe. Você está colocando o XML dentro do método `WriteCData()`?

Comment: Sim ` xml.WriteStartElement("nfeDadosMsg", URlSoapAction);
                xml.WriteCData(notaAssinada);
                xml.WriteEndElement();
                xml.WriteEndElement();` a variavel notaAssinada é que tem a string contendo o xml

Comment: sua notaAssinada tem CDATA dentro dela?

Comment: Estava olhando aqui e tem um CData na tag do QRCode e se eu tiro o CData o QRCode fica invalido

Comment: ah, então aí complica mesmo... concatenar CDATAs é complicado mas funciona se trocar os `]]>` por `]]]]><![CDATA[>`, com exceção do último `]]>`

Comment: Consegui dividindo a mensagem de cabeçalho em duas strings e concatenando o lote com a mensagem. Porém estou tendo duas declarações <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> e queria remover uma, tentei usando Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"," "); mas sem sucesso.